# Select Method of WorkSheet class failed when trying to select a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I build VBA that open an Excel Workbook, select specific Worksheet based on name, copy the sheet into new Workbook with code below.

```
Dim myBook As Workbook
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet1, targetSheet2, targetName1, targetName2, targetDir As String
    
    targetDir = "C:\Users\kamsiong.ong\Desktop\temp"
    
    targetSheet1 = "Uob(Airpay)Wallet Paid"
    targetName1 = targetDir + "\" + targetSheet1 + ".csv"
    
    targetSheet2 = "Uob(Airpay)Offline Payment"
    targetName2 = targetDir + "\" + targetSheet2 + ".csv"
    
    
    Set myBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\kamsiong.ong\Desktop\temp\Daily Financial Report Tool -12092021")
    
    For Each sheet In myBook.Worksheets
    
        If sheet.Name = targetSheet1 Then
            
            myBook.Sheets(targetSheet1).Select # Error
            myBook.Sheets(targetSheet1).Copy
            ChDir targetDir
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=targetName1, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, CreateBackup:=False
            
        ElseIf sheet.Name = targetSheet2 Then
        
            myBook.Sheets(targetSheet2).Select
            myBook.Sheets(targetSheet2).Copy
            ChDir targetDir
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=targetName2, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, CreateBackup:=False
                
        End If
        
    Next sheet
    
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Set myBook = Nothing
```

However, my program hit a bug that says `Select Method of WorkSheet class failed` within the `For-Loop` when I select Worksheet by name `myBook.Sheets(targetSheet1).Select`.

[image]

Please advise what could be the reason of error.

Comment: Please, comment the lines `myBook.Sheets(targetSheet1).Select` and `myBook.Sheets(targetSheet1).Copy` and use instead `sheet.Copy`... Probably, the workbook keeping the sheet in discussion was not activated, but selecting/activating, only consumes Excel resources and do not bring any benefit.

Comment: Stop using `Select` (see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)). This is a bad practice and you easily run into errors. • Note that you can only select a worksheet if the workbook is the active one. But I really recommend not using `Select` and do as FaneDuru explained. • Also avoid `ActiveWorkbook`  and `ActiveWindow` both times you can use `myBook` instead.

Comment: While this isn't the cause of your problem - Please also note that `Dim targetSheet1, targetSheet2, targetName1, targetName2, targetDir As String` will only declare `targetDir` as `String` while the rest are declared as `Variant`, you have to declare each variable's type explicitly e.g. `Dim targetSheet1 As String, targetSheet2 As String, targetName1 As String, targetName2 As String, targetDir As String`

Answer (score 4):

The sheet is **hidden** - that's why it can't be selected. See last entry of properties-screenshot.

As others already stated: `select` is not necessary to copy the  sheet.
You could simply use `myBook.Sheets(targetSheet1).Copy` without the select.

But a hidden sheet can't be copied - so unless you make it visible you will have the error in the copy-row.

Comment: One more reason to stay away from `.Select` :) Well spotted!

Comment: A side note: **One sheet must be visible.** A **single** sheet cannot be copied to a **new** workbook if it is hidden or very hidden. A **single** sheet can be copied to **another** workbook even if it is hidden, but not if it is very hidden. **Multiple** sheets can be copied to a **new** workbook as long as one of them is visible (the order, e.g. in an array, is not relevant ), although any very hidden sheets will not be copied (no error). **Multiple** sheets can be copied to **another** workbook even if they all are hidden. Again, if any are very hidden, they will not be copied (no error).